# Where might I find a copy of the 1983 RPG "Other Suns"?

Tags: product-identification

For a little while now, I have been trying to find a copy of the 1983 TTRPG *Other Suns*, published by Fantasy Games Unlimited online. I have been able to find copies of the shipbuilding supplement *Alderson Yards Shipbook* from 1984, but the original two books seem to be completely lost to the world, at least online.

And so, I ask: are there any repositories of older RPGs that this game may be on? (Preferably something that doesn't break the bank, but I'm desperate at this point.

Comment: Possible duplicate on [How to acquire an out of print game?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68478)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Purchase a copy.

A search for the title and author quickly brought up vendors with the books or boxed sets in stock.

E.g.:

- [Noble Knight Games](https://www.nobleknight.com/P/2147355941/Other-Suns)
- [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?i=stripbooks&rh=p_27%3ANiall%20Shapero&s=relevancerank&text=Niall%20Shapero&ref=dp_byline_sr_book_1)
- [Ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/314505778062)

### Contact the Author

The author,  Niall Shapero, holds the copyright to the books and may even have extra copies in their possession that they are willing to sell to you directly.